# Cannot hide/remove an Activity's title

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I cannot hide the title's view from an `Activity` that I'm styling as a `Dialog`.

`android:windowNoTitle` is set to *`false`* in the reference style, and `RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle)` is called from `OnCreate`.

Is there another setting for completely removing the title's view from an Activity?

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog_Configuration" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>      
</style>
```

**ConfigurationView**

```
[Activity(
    Label = "Configuration",
    MainLauncher = false,        
    Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog_Configuration",        
    ExcludeFromRecents = true
)]

public class ConfigurationView : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Configuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`

Comment: Do you have a toolbar in your Activity?

Comment: Your shared methods not working in project?Maybe activity has something different.

Comment: @samis Have you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Stanojkovic - Removing the namespace `android` from the `windowNoTitle` attribute worked (which I noticed looking through the source).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using toolbar? You can try this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

or

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//will hide the title.
getSupportActionBar().hide(); //hide the title bar.
```

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()` returns *null*

Comment: if you are using toolbar in your activitiy layout after `setContentView(R.layout.youractivity)` you need to set toolbar to your toolbar as actionbar. `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` Then when you call `getSupportActionBar()` you don't get null value.

Answer (score 0):

While you have removed the *title*, you also need to remove the *title bar* as well. Try adding the following line to your onCreate method:

```java
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: `getSupportActionBar()` returns *null*

Answer (score 0):

Write this in the `OnCreate` method just after `SetContentView`:

```
ActionBar.Hide();
```

Alternatively, you could try this

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```